# IndentationError: unexpected unindent can't find the issue

Tags: python

So this is the full code

```
from itertools import imap
import threading
import time
import hashlib
import sys

__b58chars = '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz'
__b58base = len(__b58chars)

global PUBKEY_ADDRESS
global SCRIPT_ADDRESS
PUBKEY_ADDRESS = 12
SCRIPT_ADDRESS = 8

def rev_hex(s):
    return s.decode('hex')[::-1].encode('hex')


def int_to_hex(i, length=1):
    s = hex(i)[2:].rstrip('L')
    s = "0"*(2*length - len(s)) + s
    return rev_hex(s)


def var_int(i):
    if i < 0xfd:
        return int_to_hex(i)
    elif i <= 0xffff:
        return "fd" + int_to_hex(i, 2)
    elif i <= 0xffffffff:
        return "fe" + int_to_hex(i, 4)
    else:
        return "ff" + int_to_hex(i, 8)


Hash = lambda x: hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(x).digest()).digest()


hash_encode = lambda x: x[::-1].encode('hex')


hash_decode = lambda x: x.decode('hex')[::-1]


def header_to_string(res):
    pbh = res.get('prev_block_hash')
    if pbh is None:
        pbh = '0'*64

    return int_to_hex(res.get('version'), 4) \
        + rev_hex(pbh) \
        + rev_hex(res.get('merkle_root')) \
        + int_to_hex(int(res.get('timestamp')), 4) \
        + int_to_hex(int(res.get('bits')), 4) \
        + int_to_hex(int(res.get('nonce')), 4) \
        + int_to_hex(int(res.get('BirthdayA')), 4) \ # this is where it says the error is
        + int_to_hex(int(res.get('BirthdayB')), 4)

def hex_to_int(s):
    return int('0x' + s[::-1].encode('hex'), 16)


def header_from_string(s):
    return {
        'version': hex_to_int(s[0:4]),
        'prev_block_hash': hash_encode(s[4:36]),
        'merkle_root': hash_encode(s[36:68]),
        'timestamp': hex_to_int(s[68:72]),
        'bits': hex_to_int(s[72:76]),
        'nonce': hex_to_int(s[76:80]),
        'BirthdayA': hex_to_int(s[80:84]),
        'BirthdayB': hex_to_int(s[84:88]),
    }


############ functions from pywallet #####################



def hash_160(public_key):
    try:
        md = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
        md.update(hashlib.sha256(public_key).digest())
        return md.digest()
    except:
        import ripemd
        md = ripemd.new(hashlib.sha256(public_key).digest())
        return md.digest()


def public_key_to_pubkey_address(public_key):
    return hash_160_to_pubkey_address(hash_160(public_key))


def public_key_to_bc_address(public_key):
    """ deprecated """
    return public_key_to_pubkey_address(public_key)


def hash_160_to_pubkey_address(h160, addrtype=None):
    """ deprecated """
    if not addrtype:
        addrtype = PUBKEY_ADDRESS
    return hash_160_to_address(h160, addrtype)


def hash_160_to_pubkey_address(h160):
    return hash_160_to_address(h160, PUBKEY_ADDRESS)


def hash_160_to_script_address(h160):
    return hash_160_to_address(h160, SCRIPT_ADDRESS)


def hash_160_to_address(h160, addrtype = 12):
    """ Checks if the provided hash is actually 160bits or 20 bytes long and returns the address, else None
    """
    if h160 is None or len(h160) is not 20:
        return None
    vh160 = chr(addrtype) + h160
    h = Hash(vh160)
    addr = vh160 + h[0:4]
    return b58encode(addr)

def bc_address_to_hash_160(addr):
    if addr is None or len(addr) is 0:
        return None
    bytes = b58decode(addr, 25)
    return bytes[1:21] if bytes is not None else None


def b58encode(v):
    """encode v, which is a string of bytes, to base58."""

    long_value = 0L
    for (i, c) in enumerate(v[::-1]):
        long_value += (256**i) * ord(c)

    result = ''
    while long_value >= __b58base:
        div, mod = divmod(long_value, __b58base)
        result = __b58chars[mod] + result
        long_value = div
    result = __b58chars[long_value] + result

    # Bitcoin does a little leading-zero-compression:
    # leading 0-bytes in the input become leading-1s
    nPad = 0
    for c in v:
        if c == '\0':
            nPad += 1
        else:
            break

    return (__b58chars[0]*nPad) + result


def b58decode(v, length):
    """ decode v into a string of len bytes."""
    long_value = 0L
    for (i, c) in enumerate(v[::-1]):
        long_value += __b58chars.find(c) * (__b58base**i)

    result = ''
    while long_value >= 256:
        div, mod = divmod(long_value, 256)
        result = chr(mod) + result
        long_value = div
    result = chr(long_value) + result

    nPad = 0
    for c in v:
        if c == __b58chars[0]:
            nPad += 1
        else:
            break

    result = chr(0)*nPad + result
    if length is not None and len(result) != length:
        return None

    return result


def EncodeBase58Check(vchIn):
    hash = Hash(vchIn)
    return b58encode(vchIn + hash[0:4])


def DecodeBase58Check(psz):
    vchRet = b58decode(psz, None)
    key = vchRet[0:-4]
    csum = vchRet[-4:]
    hash = Hash(key)
    cs32 = hash[0:4]
    if cs32 != csum:
        return None
    else:
        return key




########### end pywallet functions #######################
import os

def random_string(length):
    return b58encode(os.urandom(length))

def timestr():
    return time.strftime("[%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S]")



### logger
import logging
import logging.handlers

logger = logging.getLogger('electrum')

def init_logger(logfile):
    hdlr = logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler(logfile)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s', "[%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S]")
    hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(hdlr)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def print_log(*args):
    logger.info(" ".join(imap(str, args)))

def print_warning(message):
    logger.warning(message)
```

## I've tried everything, from using different editors to re-writing the lines...no luck

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/run_electrum_server", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('electrum-server==0.9', 'run_electrum_server')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 528, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1401, in run_script
    exec(script_code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/electrum_server-0.9-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/run_electrum_server", line 34, in <module>

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/electrumserver/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/electrum_server-0.9-py2.7.egg/electrumserver/utils.py", line 74
    + int_to_hex(int(res.get('BirthdayA')), 4) \
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
Starting server as daemon
nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout
```

Comment: show the traceback with the line it's on

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1401, in run_script
    exec(script_code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/electrum_server-0.9-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/run_electrum_server", line 34, in <module>

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/electrumserver/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/electrum_server-0.9-py2.7.egg/electrumserver/utils.py", line 74
    + int_to_hex(int(res.get('BirthdayA')), 4) \
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: have you tried removing all of the backslashes and putting the block inside another set of parens?

Comment: Copying and pasting your code into an editor, then getting rid of that "this is where it says the error is," then running it, results in no errors.  Either you're using a broken in interpreter (unlikely) or the error exists at a higher level somehow.  How are you running the code?

Answer (score 1):

Your code produces no error here.

Probably is just a tab/space indentation consistency issue: if you use 4 spaces for indentation, be consistent with that, and don't use tabs, otherwise things with different indentation levels may line up, resulting in such error.

Comment: perhaps a look at the whole code may reveal something, still learning how to format the code here though

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely caused by some problem with the backslashes at end of line.

Using a set of parentheses around *all* the lines will avoid the problem.

i.e. instead of:

```
a() \
+ b()
```

use:

```
(a()
+ b())
```